# Powerapps Form: Possible to have default value from one datasource, items from another?

Tags: powerapps

I am building a Powerapp that will allow users to choose a project from a SharePoint list and have that selection pre-populate some items in a form.  There are other items in the form that I have changed to Drop Down  boxes whose items are pulled from other SharePoint lists.  So far so good, but the users have one requirement I cannot figure out:

'Engineer' must have a default value pulled from the selected project (from `Project_Selector`).  The user must also be able to overwrite that default value with a selection from the Drop Down (from `pkg_Engineer`).  The default value is not necessarily in the item list.

What I have done:

- Replaced the Text Input box for the Engineer Data Card with a Drop Down
- Set *items* to `pkg_Engineer.Name`  to populate the Drop Down choices
- Set *Default* to `Project_Selector.Selected.Name`

On preview, I expect to see Engineer pre-populated with "Fitzsimmons" (an item not in the list) and Drop Down choices of "Adams", "Baker", "Charles".

What I see is the default value of "Adams".

How can I pre-populate a Drop Down with a value not in the items list like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a collection and populate that with your names. Then set dropdown.items to be your collection

Comment: To expand on this: On the drop down ('Project_Selector') where the project is selected, OnSelect= 'ClearCollect(MyCollection,{Title:Project_Selector.Selected.'Project Lead'}); Collect(MyCollection,pkg_Engineer.Title);'  Then Engineer.items was set to MyCollection.